# HTML img tag incorrect?

Tags: html, image, tags

I'm trying to figure out why it isn't showing. 
The image is in an images folder, but other then that this is it.

```
<img src="images/rarrow.jpg" width="31" height="31" alt="right arrow">
```

Comment: What tag is incorrect?...  Could you please provide some code?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML code or provide a link to your page?

Comment: Do you see any messages in the browser console?

Comment: It seems to look correct.  Are you sure that you are using the correct source for the image or possibly another element on the page is not allowing the image to display?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you wrote an incorrect path to the image. You should generally get used to using either Firebug (a plugin for Firefox) and/or Google Chrome's inspector (which is there by default on Chrome). If you're using any of those, you can right click->inspect element.

Go through the HTML elements till you reach the `<img>`, hover over the value of the `src` attribute, probably the image will now show because of an incorrect path. Now you can keep editing the path till you get it correctly. Bear in mind the path to the html file you are currently editing, you may need to go up one or more directory. Use `../images/rarrow.jpg` to move up one directory `../../images/rarrow.jpg` to move up two directories, and so on.